# I got error cloning my project from github on server

Tags: git, ssh

I uploaded my project at github private repository with ssh public key

and I connected to my remote Ubuntu 18 Server with ssh command, as I added my public ssh key
into ~/.ssh/authorized_keys priorly.

But I got error cloning my project :

```
root@myserver:/var/www/html# git clone git@github.com:myaccount/yt3.git
Cloning into 'yt3'...
identity_sign: private key /root/.ssh/id_rsa contents do not match public
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I have:

```
root@myserver:~/.ssh# ls -la
total 28
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Dec  8 16:40 .
drwx------ 10 root root 4096 Dec  8 16:44 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  788 Dec  8 08:30 authorized_keys
-rwx------  1 root root  182 Mar  9  2019 config
-rw-------  1 root root 1675 Feb 26  2019 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  394 Dec  8 16:40 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3538 Dec  8 16:40 known_hosts
```

## cat config

```
Host bitbucket.org
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    Hostname bitbucket.org
    User git

Host github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    Hostname github.com
    User git
```

What did I miss ?

Thanks!

Comment: `identity_sign: private key /root/.ssh/id_rsa contents do not match public` tells it all.

Comment: Have I also to replace content of /root/.ssh/id_rsa (my private key) on server ?

Comment: You should do `ssh-keygen -yf id_rsa > id_rsa.pub` to re-generate the correct public key from the private key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a public ssh key to *your* `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` will not allow GitHub or BitBucket to authenticate you.

GitHub or BitBucket won't use your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` at all.

You must register your [public key to GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) (or a [separate key to BitBucket](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/#Step-3.-Add-the-public-key-to-your-Account-settings), adding the same is not a recommended good practice).

And if your config file includes the user `git`,  you don't need to repeat it in your SSH URL:

```
git clone github.com:myaccount/yt3.git
```